# Possibility of continued partial electric discharge

Tags: electric-fields, conductors, dielectric

Consider a pipe with a tear drop shaped conductor located at the center and an electric field parallel to the pipe in it. The electric field is stronger at the tear-drop conductor and looks as in the figure below. Assume that the strength of the electric field is just below that of the breakdown voltage of air but is strong enough so that the field strength at the rear end of the tear drop is above the breakdown voltage where the conductor is the sharpest.

[image]

In the diagram above, the highlighted blue circle is the region where the electric field strength exceeds the breakdown voltage of air.

(i) Is it possible to have a partial electric break down such that the air in that localized region arcs while the rest of the air remains insulating?

(ii) If so, in case the tear drop is grounded, would the arcing continue indefinitely as the tear drop does not change potential?

(iii) What sort of currents would we expect to see in such arcs (magnitude of current)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge